# Struggling with meaning of would

Tags: modal-verbs

What does it even mean?

> They all called me "little dude" now—even the jocks. These big dudes I barely even knew before would knuckle-punch me in 
>   the hallways now.

Imaginary situation? Habits?
Here we have 'in the hallways now' as if it has already happened. It refers us to a repeated action, doesn't it?

Comment: Despite the "now", this is a past-tense passage.  "Called", "knew" and "would" are all simple past tense forms here.  The "would" represents a past-tense intention, inclination or habit.

Comment: would in that sentence is the same as "used to".This is a narrative past use.

Comment: 'Now' is a marker that the speaker is annoyed about the situation. This is a direct speech, where 'now' tells us in addition that it is a literary rendition of the speaker's original informal speech.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "now" is referring to the time period at which the story takes place at that point. "Would" is being used normally in this sentence.

Comment: Could I see it as an action that was repeated more than one time?

Comment: The passage does seem to be saying that the speaker would get knuckle-punched repeatedly.

Comment: 'Would' in the context is a marker of habitual actions in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the "now", this is a past-tense passage. "Called", "knew" and "would" are all simple past tense forms here. The "would" represents a past-tense intention, inclination or habit.

"Would" in that sentence is the same as "used to". This is a narrative past use.